# Is x in the code copied or taken as a mutable ref in the closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I am basically trying to understand why add_to_x has a trait of FnOnce.

```
let mut x = 5;
let mut add_to_x = |n: i32| {
    x += n;
    x
};
let m = add_to_x(5);
println!("x: {}", x);
println!("m: {}", m);
```

Also, if I assign add_to_x to another variable, would the closure be copied or moved?

Comment: "I am basically trying to understand why add_to_x has a trait of FnOnce." FWIW all closures have `FnOne`, as `FnOnce` is a supertrait of `FnMut` which is a supertrait of `Fn`: if you can call a function any number of times, you can call it once. Here `add_to_x` implements both `FnOnce` and `FnMut`, as (as jthulhu replied) the captured `x` still has type `i32`, and thus the captured value doesn't get consumed by returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, in closures, Rust passes values by reference. `x` in the closure behaves as a `&mut x`, except its type is still `i32` (it is dereferenced automatically by the compiler whenever you use it).

In particular, since `&mut T: !Clone` for any `T`, `add_to_x` is not clonable (in particular, it cannot be copied). It's easy to show this in an example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    let mut add_to_x = |n: i32| {
        x += n;
        x
    };
    let mut add_to_x_bis = add_to_x;
    let m = add_to_x(5);
    let _ = add_to_x_bis(5);
    println!("x: {}", x);
    println!("m: {}", m);
}
```

(see the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8eb54d02bd86128f51b5dfb936901e31)).

This will fail with the following error message, which is pretty clear

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `add_to_x`
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
7 |     let mut add_to_x_bis = add_to_x;
  |                            -------- value moved here
8 |     let m = add_to_x(5);
  |             ^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
  |
note: closure cannot be moved more than once as it is not `Copy` due to moving the variable `x` out of its environment
```

Think about what would happen if it was possible to have two instances of `add_to_x` valid at the same time. The two of them would be holding an exclusive reference to `x`, which is forbidden.

Hence, to answer your question, the closure is *moved*.

Besides, `add_to_x` is an `FnMut`, which is stronger than `FnOnce`. `FnOnce` means that the closure can be executed once. It's the only guarantee that this trait provides. `FnMut` means that the closure can be executed any number of times, but the call method takes a mutable reference to `self`, that is to say, you need to be able to produce a mutable reference to the closure to call it (hence the requirement of `add_to_x` to be a mutable variable).

In this case, `add_to_x` mutates something that is behind an exclusive borrow, but it can be called several times, so it's an `FnMut` closure.

Comment: Thank you @jthulhu.

What would m be? Is it a mut ref of x, or a copy of x?

Comment: `m` is a copy of `x`.

Comment: @saimanohar `m` is a *copy* of `x`, that is, when the closure returns `x`, it actually dereferences the mutable borrow to `x`.  Since `i32: Copy`, the actual `x` is copied.

Comment: You can see this behaviour if you replace `x` by an owned value, either a newtype or a `String` (in which case you'll need to replace `n` by `&n.to_string()`). Then the closure has to consume the string in order to return it, and `add_to_x` becomes a strict `FnOnce`.